# Should I use "make" or "makes"?

Tags: verb-agreement

Should I use *make* or *makes* in the following sentence?

> I’m confident that my expertise in this field **makes** me the candidate best suited for this position.

Answer (score 2):

makes, because you say "my expertise makes", (equivalent to "it makes")